# Python: How to define functions in loops using outer-scope variables?

Tags: python, loops, function-definition, python-nonlocal

I want to define a function inside a loop using and changing variables which have been defined within the same loop iteration.

I would expect that `nonlocal` is just what i need here, but if i implement it like this

```
for i in range(5):
    obj = {"start": i}
    def update():
        nonlocal obj
        obj["next"] = obj["start"] + 1
        print(obj)
    update()
```

i get

```
  File "/path/to/test.py", line 4
    nonlocal obj
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'obj' found
```

using Python 3.10.12 on Linux.

Comment: this should be in a _function_

Comment: Why though? Define the function outside the loop and pass the object as an argument.

Comment: If no function is around `update`, use `global` instead of `nonlocal`.

Comment: Aaah ok, I got it. I thought that `nonlocal` would just take the next outer scope, which in this case indeed is the same as `global`. However it seems like `nonlocal` only allows "non-global" outer scopes. Thanks a lot!